# Android 7.0 NDK thread_join error

Tags: android, android-ndk

I used `pthread_join(tid,0);` in Android NDK
I got a crash in Android 7.0+, but run normally at Android 6.x or lower version

Crash stack info:

```
03-28 11:38:06.460 32510-32510 A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-28 11:38:06.461 32510-32510 A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'HUAWEI/VIE-AL10/HWVIE:7.0/HUAWEIVIE-AL10/C00B356:user/release-keys'
03-28 11:38:06.461 32510-32510 A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
03-28 11:38:06.461 32510-32510 A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
03-28 11:38:06.461 32510-32510 A/DEBUG: pid: 32024, tid: 32024, name: com.yoosee  >>> com.yoosee <<<
03-28 11:38:06.461 32510-32510 A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0xcac80000
03-28 11:38:06.461 32510-32510 A/DEBUG:     r0 cac7ffff  r1 00000001  r2 00000000  r3 00000000
03-28 11:38:06.461 32510-32510 A/DEBUG:     r4 c4f01920  r5 e512ca38  r6 00000000  r7 ff908bf8
03-28 11:38:06.461 32510-32510 A/DEBUG:     r8 00000000  r9 ef005400  sl ef00548c  fp ff908bc4
03-28 11:38:06.461 32510-32510 A/DEBUG:     ip efa1a85c  sp ff908af0  lr ef9d96d3  pc ef9d96d6  cpsr 200f0030
03-28 11:38:06.463 32510-32510 A/DEBUG: backtrace:
03-28 11:38:06.463 32510-32510 A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 000476d6  /systembbc.so (_Z23__pthread_internal_findl+25)
03-28 11:38:06.463 32510-32510 A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00047715  /systembbc.so (pthread_join+24)
03-28 11:38:06.463 32510-32510 A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 000316e1  /data/app/com.yoosee-1b/armbmediaplayer.so (_ZN11MediaPlayer11StopSessionEv+232)
03-28 11:38:06.463 32510-32510 A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 0002fc2b  /data/app/com.yoosee-1b/armbmediaplayer.so
03-28 11:38:06.463 32510-32510 A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0088699f  /data/app/com.yoosee-1/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x7fd000)
03-28 11:38:06.593 648-32307 W/AudioFlinger: RecordThread: buffer overflow
```

Comment: Please post the text of the log and not an image. That's a pain to read.

Comment: I post the text of the log now

Comment: `/systembbc.so`? That doesn't look right.